# Do the 'Augment X' skills affect 'X-Touched' damage?

Tags: tactics-ogre-psp

I am doing my 5thish playthrough of Tactics Ogre and for something different have Denam set up as a Rune Fencer. I have him with Divine Magic, a spear and Augment Light.

I typically get someone to cast Instill Light on him, which will mean his Augment Light skill is raised slightly whenever he hits one or two enemies with his spear.

I am curious whether the Augment Light skill will increase the Light-Touched damage as it levels up, or if it's always the same amount (it seems to be a percentage of the weapon damage currently, maybe 25%).

Answer (score -1):

The Light-Touched damage *should* scale separately from Augment Light. Unfortunately I couldn't find any specifics/damage tables to prove my point.